# Nodejs Receiving errro "options.hostname" property must be one of type string, undefined, or null. Received type object at validateHost

Tags: node.js, server

I am trying to do a post request to open permID API.

The request url is https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/match/file?Content-Type=multipart%2Fform-data

I have tried writing the code from scratch as well copy and past working parameters, headers, and body value from the code produced by postman.

The code I wrote is commented out.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');
// const http = require('http');
// const https = require('https');
const util = require('util')


// Sets an initial port. We"ll use this later in our listener
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;


app.use(cors());

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

// Service end-point (search) 

// app.get('/upload', function (req, res) {

//   var options = {
//     method: 'GET',
//     url: 'https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/match/file?Content-Type=multipart%2Fform-data',
//     headers: {
//       'cache-control': 'no-cache',
//       'x-openmatch-dataType': 'Organization',
//       'x-openmatch-numberOfMatchesPerRecord': '1',
//       'x-ag-access-token': '96CT8NAgnieeuiYA2YPeNMnbPMfHu4W8'
//     },
//     formData: {
//       file: undefined
//     }
//   };

//   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
//     if (error) throw new Error(error);
//     console.log(response)
//     console.log(body);
//   });

// });

// function dataReturned(e) {
//   console.log("Success!");
//   finalRes.end(e);
// }

// const server = http.createServer(app)
// server.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`app started! at port ${PORT}`);
// });
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": [
    "api",
    "thomsonreuters",
    "com"
  ],
  "path": [
    "permid",
    "match",
    "file"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "x-openmatch-numberOfMatchesPerRecord": "1",
    "x-openmatch-dataType": "Organization",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "101e3dbe-96bf-4b1c-9fce-8dad5f4ff975"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
req.end();
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear. Your options.hostname here is an array, not the string that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [HTTPS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html), it looks like `hostname` should be a string rather than an array.

Instead of

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": [
    "api",
    "thomsonreuters",
    "com"
  ],
...
```

try

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "api.thomsonreuters.com",
...
``
```

Comment: After updating that I get the following in terminal

$ node index.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>An error occurred.</h1>
<p>Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.<br/>
Please try again later.</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I believe you need to do a similar change to `options.path` - it is a string, not an array of strings

Comment: That has not chaged the result of what I am receiving. Refering to the original code + changing the hostname and path to strings, I am curiouse as to uploading the file to the api may be the problem. 

Looking at the code I dont see a path for the file attachment but am unsure if there is something i am missing with that since postman handled that in the example code.